# Why i have padding above left first lorem ipsum?

Tags: html, css

I am creating html templemate because I want to send some mails. But I have problem. In my templemate on the left side is padding on th I think. But I can not delete it and I do not know how to delete it. I want to have that left elements on the same level like this on the right side. Can you help me? I am appreciate help. It is very important for me.

```html
<html> 
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 100%;
          }
          
          #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
          }
          
          .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
          }
          
          .ExternalClass,
          .ExternalClass p,
          .ExternalClass span,
          .ExternalClass font,
          .ExternalClass td,
          .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
          
          .tablereset {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 640px !important;
            line-height: 100% !important
          }
          
          .button {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
          }
          
          .devicewidthsocial {
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
  
          table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
          
          table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
          }
          
          td.boxesfont {
            font-size: 17px !important;
            font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important
          }
          
          td[class*=font-resize] {
            font-size: 140%!important
          }
         
          @media only screen and (max-width:640px) {
            a[href="tel"],
            a[href="sms"] {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #ffffff;
              pointer-events: none;
              cursor: default;
            }
            tr.removemobile {
              display: none;
            }
            td[class*=threecolumnphoto] {
              padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
            table[class*=button] {
              float: none;
            }
            table.removemobile {
              display: none;
            }
            table.tablereset {
              margin: 0 auto;
              width: 440px !important;
              line-height: 100% !important
            }
            table[class*=devicewidth] {
              width: 440px!important;
              text-align: center!important;
              float: none!important;
              display: table!important;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidthinner] {
              width: 400px!important;
              text-align: center!important;
              float: none!important;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidthinner3] {
              width: 173px!important;
              float: none!important;
            }
            img[class*=logoImg] {
              width: 110px!important;
              height: auto!important;
            }
          }
          
          @media only screen and (max-width:479px) {
            table.removemobile {
              display: none;
            }
            table[class*=tablereset] {
              margin: 0 auto;
              width: 280px !important;
              line-height: 100% !important
            }
            img[class*=logoImg] {
              width: 100px!important;
              height: auto!important;
            }
            td[class*=threecolumnphoto] {
              padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidthright] {
              width: 160px!important;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidth] {
              width: 280px!important;
              float: none!important;
              display: table!important;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidthinner] {
              width: 240px!important;
              float: none!important;
            }
            table[class*=devicewidthinner3] {
              width: 173px!important;
              float: none!important;
            }
            table[class*=button] {
              float: none!important;
            }
            table[class*=button] td,
            table[class*=button] td a {
              font-size: 12px!important;
            }
            td[class*=oswaldfont] {
              font-size: large!important;
            }
          }
    
        </style>
      </head>
      <body style="margin:0; padding:0">
        <table class="tablereset" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="640">
                <table class="devicewidth" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="58" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <p style="font-family:Open Sans; text-align: center; color: #606060;">Nowy outlet mebli tapicerowanych</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px" height="18" width="640">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="640" align="center">
                        <table class="devicewidthinner" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:18px; color:#b2b2b2;line-height: 18px;text-align: center;">
                                <div class="strike">
                                  <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #606060;">Lorem ipsum                                    <p style="font-weight: 400;">Lorem ipsum</p></span>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20" width="640"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    
        <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #dddddd;" class="tablereset" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="640">
                <table class="devicewidth" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="640" style="margin:0 auto;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="640" align="center">
                        <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" width="200">
                                <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300; color: #606060;">Lorem ipsum</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 700; font-size: 22px;line-height:24px; color: #606060; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;">Lorem ipsum </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="640" height="25">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left">
                                        <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300; color: #606060;">Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem 
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                              <td align="left" width="1" valign="middle">
                                <span style="width:2px; height:80px; background:#ececec; margin-top: 70px; display:block;"></span>
                              </td>
                              <td width="317" align="center">
                                <table class="devicewidthinner" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="317">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left" width="640">
                                        <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 20px;" class="devicewidthinner" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300; color: #606060;">Lorem ipsum
                                                <span style="color: red;text-decoration: line-through;">
                                                 <span style="color: #606060; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;">
                                                  <span style="margin-left:5px;">$</span></span>
                                                </span>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" height="5" width="640"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="640" align="left" style="font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px;line-height:24px;"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #606060;">Lorem ipsum </span><span style="color: #e4001b; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; margin-left: 30px;">$</span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="left">
                                                <table style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td width="640" align="left" class="robotofont" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,Roboto;font-weight: 300;">
                                                        <p style="-webkit-margin-before: 0;-webkit-margin-after: 0; color: #606060; margin-top: 15px; font-weight: 400;">Wymiary:</p>
                                                        <p style="-webkit-margin-before: 0;-webkit-margin-after: 0; color: #606060; margin-top: 10px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Długość: </span><span style="margin-left: 15px;">188 cm</span></p>
                                                        <p style="-webkit-margin-before: 0;-webkit-margin-after: 0; color: #606060; margin-top: 2px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Szerokość: </span>&nbsp 85 cm</p>
                                                        <p style="-webkit-margin-before: 0;-webkit-margin-after: 0; color: #606060; margin-top: 2px"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Wysokość: </span>&nbsp 90 cm</p>
                                                      </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
```

Comment: Did you remove the margins from the paragraphs & headings too?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
          table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            vertical-align: bottom;
          }
```

I think the elements on the left are on the same level as the ones on the right